# How to configure HTTP requests between two applications on OpenShift

Tags: geoserver, java, openshift

I have deployed a GeoServer and a Java EE REST API on OpenShift as non-scalable applications.

From the REST API I'm trying to connect to GeoServer using Apache httpclient. When I'm requesting GeoServer on OpenShift from my REST API installed locally it works (so the application logic is working). But when I deploy the REST API on OpenShift and try the same requests. I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.net.BindException: Permission denied

at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
at java.net.Socket.bind(Socket.java:631)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

It seems to me that the communication between these two applications is stopped by OpenShift in some way. All the requests to the REST API that are not involving an internal request to GeoServer are working fine.

Is there some setting in OpenShift that I've missed?

Comment: Do you have an example of how you are making the call in your code - it would be helpful to see the calls you are making.